# 200 students are placed in a circle, each of them wears a hat with a real number written on it.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This question was asked when I tried to unlock Olympiad Math questions. The question states that:

"200 students are placed in a circle, each of them wears a hat with a real number written on it. 2 numbers inscribed on 2 neighboring hats always have a difference between 1 and 3 (in absolute value), and the sum of the 200 numbers inscribed on the hats is equal to 1600.
Find an interval [A, B] with A and B integers such that it is certain that there are 5 adjacent students whose numbers written on the hats have a sum in the interval [A, B]. Among all the possible intervals, we will choose the one maximizing A then, if necessary, the one minimizing B. Once this interval has been found, give the value of A⋅B."

I tried to use the fact that $$\sum_{k=1}^{200}(a_{k}-a_{k+2})=0$$ and also tried to re-organize the sum of 5 consecutive numbers $$a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}+a_{k}+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}$$  however nothing useful was found.

The website gives a hint: take inspiration from the C2 problem of IMO 2011. I enclose the solution of this problem.

[solution of IMO problem page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTfXI.png)

[solution of IMO problem page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTT8L.png)